# Session-based authentication for a RESTful webservice in Glassfish

Tags: session, rest, glassfish, cluster-computing, restful-authentication

**The Problem**

I'm creating an application that runs on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and exposes a RESTful API in an environment where authentication is expensive. Passing the credentials and authenticating every request isn't feasible - I need a session-based approach.

I'm looking at using BASIC auth and in-memory session replication (the app needs to support deployment in a cluster). In-memory replication seems expensive considering I'm only sharing "logged in" state - every other component of the applicaiton is stateless.

My question is: **Is there a better alternative?**

e.g. Can I configure Glassfish to persist session state to a database, instead of using in-memory replication?

I've considered a "session as a resource" approach e.g. POST to /session to login, DELETE /session/{id} to logout. This provides more control, however it's more difficult for the service consumers (vs something like BASIC auth).